# Trigger slide zoom with space key

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide which contains with some content that is always shown, a [slide zoom](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-zoom-for-powerpoint-to-bring-your-presentation-to-life-9d6c58cd-2125-4d29-86b1-0097c7dc47d7) and two text boxes that appear through animations. In the presentation, I first want to zoom to the detail slide, go back to the main slide, and then show the text boxes.

To trigger the slide zoom, I need to click onto the miniature slide. However, I usually forget this and hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> instead - hence I show the text box too early. So my question is if it is also possible to add the zoom to the animation order, so that it is also triggered by the space key.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a 'slide zoom'? The 'zoom' animation just makes an object appear out of nowhere by scaling it from 0 to 100%. The best way I can think of based on limited information is to make a copy of your initial slide, then insert a slide between these two copies that does whichever zoomed in content you require. This way, space will always cycle forward in the order you want to.

Comment: One approach would be to set the show up in KIOSK mode. You'd have to add your own navigation buttons to go to the next slide etc, but it would prevent you from accidentally advancing by hitting space or any other key.

Comment: @MiG: Slide zoom was a new feature in PowerPoint 2019. I've added a link to the documentation in the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still on 2016. All animations have a reversed counterpart though, I assume this is still the same in 2019. If not, the 'cloning slide' option above might be your best bet. slide 1 -> zoom in animation -> slide 2 (which is slide 1 without the zoom in animation).